# Is 'success' a valid attribute for a jquery click function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm opening a PDF file in a new tab by using a jQuery().click on a anchor,

```
<a class="open" id="popen"></a>

$("#popen").attr({
            href: filepath,
            alt: "pdf",
            target: '_blank',
            success: window.location = "location"
          });

          jQuery('#popen')[0].click();
```

The above code works however I wasn't aware that 'success' was a valid attribute of an anchor tag, I thought it only applied to Ajax call.

How is this working?

Is 'success' a valid anchor attribute?

Comment: No, `success` is not a valid attribute on an `a` element. It's also not performing any function in your code so can (and should) be removed.

Comment: Consider using an event listener instead?

Comment: refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a (Updated)

Comment: Is something using the attribute? If they are, probably using eval() which seems really bad.

Comment: @Hemakumar please don't use W3Schools as a resource. Their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) is far more comprehensive and accurate.

Comment: Well, on success it is supposed to navigate to another page which when I test it this does navigate to another page.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I will try a different method if doing it this way is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

'success' is not a valid html anchor attribute, so putting it there doesn't do or even change everything. So to keep your codes valid, you have to remove it.